# Continuity of $f_\alpha(x,y)=\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}, f_\alpha(0,0)=0$ in $(0,0).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

I've already proved that $f_\alpha$ is discontinuous if $\alpha\geq 1$. Now I want to prove (what I assume, but don't know) that $f_\alpha$ is continuous if $\alpha<1$.

The definitions of continuity I want to use are either $\epsilon,\delta $ continuity or $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for any sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.

What I've proved so far is that, if $\alpha<1$, for any $m\in\mathbb R$, we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}f_{\alpha}(x,mx)=0.$$ However, I don't know if this is sufficient - this is far from having proved that for any sequence converging to $(0,0)$ the images converge to $0$ - or isn't it? Can I deduce the statement for any sequence from this special case? Or is there another, better way to prove it? Or am I mistaken and $f_\alpha$ is discontinuous? I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Try using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. By using [polar coodinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html), as $(x,y) \to  (0,0)$, one gets
$$
|f(x,y)|=\left|\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\alpha}\right|=r^{2-2\alpha}|\cos \theta \sin \theta|\leq r^{2(1-\alpha)} \to 0
$$ for $1-\alpha>0$.